# How to get integer value from mongodb bson document using java?

Tags: java, mongodb, bson

I am trying to retrieve an integer from bson document using the following code:

```
MongoCursor<Document> cursor = collection.find().iterator();
while (cursor.hasNext()) {
    Document rowDoc = cursor.next();
    int myNum = rowDoc.getInteger("number");
}
```

then I got this exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Double cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
```

As I thought `number` is `double` my change was:

```
double myNum = rowDoc.getDouble("number");
```

But this time I got:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Double
```

I've checked the value type in mongo shell returning `number`. So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe you have mixed types. Try `((Number)rowDoc.get("number")).intValue()`

Comment: @shmosel : `public <T> T get("number", Number.class)` is more appropriate.

Comment: What you do with your `myNum` variable?

Comment: @shmosel: It solved my problem. Thanks a lot. I would still appreciate some detailed explanation.

Comment: Just a thought. Why are you storing them as double and integer if you just care about int value  ? Would it help to update the data to just include integer ? Then `int myNum = rowDoc.getInteger("number");` will work as expected.

Comment: @Veeram: Yes, I only needed int value here. I was getting exception at `org.bson.Document.getInteger`. So I wanted to check it with 'getDouble()'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `int myNum = rowDoc.getInteger("number").getValue();`